# Filtering mappings in sbt-native-packager

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-native-packager

I'm using sbt-native-packager with JavaServerAppPackaging archetype for RPM build.
However, I don't want for /etc/default and /var/run to be included in RPM.
I tried to filter linuxPackageMappings, but it doesn't contain this directories:

```
// Doesn't prints /etc/default or /var/run files
linuxPackageMappings.value.foreach(_.mappings.foreach(x => println(x._2)))
```

How do I filter this directories out?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need these folders, then you can just use the `JavaAppPackaging` plugin. The server variant does nothing more than adding these folders

Cheers,
Muki

Comment: JavaAppPackaging have another problem - it ignores my preinstall scripts, so I can't create daemon user by itself.